# RethinkDB simple pluck from nested array

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I am new to RethinkDB and have looked here and elsewhere for the answer to this. I have found several things close, but still can't seem to figure out what seems like it should be simple. I have a query:

```
r.db('common').table("counters").filter({org: 'myorg'}).pluck('counters').run()
```

That gives the following results:

```
{
  "counters": [
    {
      "aid": 0 ,
      "pid": 1000 ,
      "rid": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want is to `pluck` or somehow get a specific counter (e.g. pid). I tried `counter[0].pid`, `counters.pid` and a few others, but can't quite seem to find the magic bullet. From what I did find, I suspect this may involve a function, but am not sure where it should go. Any help is appreciated and if you dup this, please make sure it's an exact dup and not something close. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, had to change the array to an object:

```
{
  "counters": {
    "aid": 0 ,
    "pid": 1000 ,
    "rid": 0
  }
}
```

... then use `get()`, this works`r.db('common').table("counters").get('12345-1234-54321-6666-f0dac0b6b68e')('counters')('pid')`